# Support Google Keyboard emojis in textview android

Tags: android, unicode, textview, emoji, truetype

I want to support new Hangout like emojis(as in image below) of Google Keyboard in Textview of my android app. Some emojis render in the textview but many don't. Both Instagram and Whatsapp support almost of these emojis.

I have tried adding some suggested custom font .ttf and setting typeface of textview but it doesn't works.

[image]

Comment: how about trying https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Comment: I want the native way to do it. Somebody please help

Comment: did you get the solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @SyarifIbnuMiftahudinAl-Dami Yes, there was an encoding issue at source.